# If the rows of two columns are equal remove and mantaim the others - R

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I have a df with multiple columns

```
polo      cod ....   nome    students
macaé     656 ....   UFRJ    5000
caxias    789 ....   UFRJ    5000
fundao    234 ....   UFRJ    5000
niteroi   477 ....   UFF     4000
botafogo  323 ....   Unirio  1000
```

My desired df will keep these columns but remove the rows that the column name and students are equal

```
polo                    cod ....   nome    students
macaé_caxias_fundao     656 ....   UFRJ    5000
niteroi                 477 ....   UFF     4000
botafogo                323 ....   Unirio  1000
```

The code: DATA = MYDATA %>% distinct(name,students) remove the others columns that are important

Thank you very much!

Comment: Try `MYDATA %>% group_by(nome, students) %>% summarise(polo = str_c(polo, collapse = '_'), cod = first(cod))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may do a group by paste here

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
MYDATA %>%
 group_by(nome, students) %>%
 summarise(polo = str_c(polo, collapse = "_"), cod = first(cod))
```